# Can anyone identify this thick leaved crawling plant?

Tags: identification, vines

I was given a small clipping of this plant and it is really taking off.  Does anyone know what family this is?

[image: small green plant]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that's Chinese Stonecrop.

I think we're having a hard time pinning it down because this species is most commonly seen today in the form of it's red-leaf-tipped cultivar "Coral Reef Stonecrop."

My double-checking on this has led me to conclude the "Coral Reef" cultivar became so much more popular than the original that the cultivar name supplanted the real name.

Comment: Great Detective Work!

Comment: Yes, this is definitely it. I also have the "Coral Reef" variety as well but that one has very thin leaves while these are much meatier.

Comment: Additional:  Stonecrops, like various Jade Plants, have a tendency to develop red tips on their own. I would wager (this is just an educated guess) that the redder cultivars were simply stock bred for the inherent redding tendencies that they all inherently possess.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't look like Purslane to me, black thumb. I know it can get quite weedy, but it can be, and is grown as a house plant, which if controlled, is workable. I have one at home.

I think this plant up here is a species or species hybrid of Crassula.

Update: It appears to be a species of Pilea or Sedum.

Comment: Definitely a Crassula sp. Perhaps C. Radicans?

Comment: Could be. This is so tough! It might be Crassula multicava as well.